# Click on Like Button with an Apple Script

Tags: javascript, html, button, applescript

I've read some questions on the website but I can't solve my problem.
I am trying to write an appleScript that put automatically a "like" to a Instagram Photo.
Reading other topic I arrived to that:

"

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to "https://www.instagram.com/p/BZZFmzcB4sK/?hl=it&explore=true"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen').click();" in document 1
end tell
```

"

My problem is that I can't find the id of the like button. 
I tought it was "_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen" but it doesn't work.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.getElementsByClassName()` because you are using the class name. However this function returns an array of elements so you would need to take only the first one.

**Example:** `document.getElementsByClassName('_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen')[0].click();`

Answer (score 0):

SO the code will be:

```
 tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to "https://www.instagram.com/p/BZYf6mKFd4F/?taken-by=alessandrosimon"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen')[0].click();" 
end tell
```

I don't know why it is wrong... maybe is wrong the name class?
If I click theispector elemento on the Like button it show u this:

```
    <a class="_eszkz _l9yih" href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen">Mi piace</span></a>
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question, are you getting an error when you try to run it? If so can you provide some more information...

Comment: The program say me this:
tell application "Safari"
 activate
 set URL of document 1 to "https://www.instagram.com/p/BZYf6mKFd4F/?taken-by=alessandrosimon"
 do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen')[0].click();"
  --> missing value
end tell
Risultato:
missing value

Comment: In  your new code I think you missed `in document 1` at the end of your second to last line

Comment: Oh. Yes. Now i have also "in document 1 but still not work.


`tell application "Safari"
 activate set URL of document 1 to "https://www.instagram.com/p/BZYf6mKFd4F/?taken-by=alessandrosimon"
 delay 3
 do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('_8scx2 coreSpriteHeartOpen')[0].click();" in document 1
end tell `
I think that the class is wrong. is possible? Can you check it? I am not sure

Comment: Yeah man now it works! I don't know why! Thank you so much!  :D Can i ask you only one thing? (I am seriously a noob ahaha) 
"documente" for what stay for?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's an old question...
Opening the page then wait for 3 seconds is not a good idea. Because if the AppleScript click is executed before the full load of the page, this will fail. 
In fact, you must open the page, wait for the element to be loaded and then, perform the click.

Eg:

```
 tell application "Safari"

tell front document to repeat until (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7').length") is greater than 0
        end repeat
        -- Now, as th element exist, we can perform the clicl
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7')[0].click();" in front document

    end tell
```

Notice also this will work fine if you run the script inside the script editor, but will fail if you export your script as APP. To  let this work correctly with APP version of the script, you must open the security module of the system preference and grab you APP to the list.